# looping, want to print out information about an array of dictionary objects at the end of the loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, logging, nsarray, nsdictionary

This may be a few questions bundled into one, but here is the situation. I am working in objective c, and have a for loop that's going through an array of dictionary objects... like so.

```
  for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array){
         log(@"the dictionary object looks like this \n%@\n",dictionary);
         log(@"value of someProp in the current dict object is %@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"someProp"]);
  }
```

well that's all nice and dandy but I want to tidy up how it prints out to the console a little bit. I am new to objective c, but experienced in other languages. I want to do something like this in objective c (wrote it in actionscript for an example)

```
  var outputString:String;

  for (items in dictionary){
     outputString += dictionary.toString();
     outputString += "value of item in current dict object is " + dictionary [item];// etc

  }

  // now just print out the contents of outputString;
  trace(outputString);
```

the challenge I have here is collating the objects that are not of type string or NSString..

I know stuff like

```
  NSString *outputString = @"";

  for (//same loop as above in obj-c){
      outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingString:**someString**];

  }
```

but maybe I am just unfamiliar with the appropriate string method, because simply substituting **dictionary** to print out the whole dictionary object where it reads **someString** will produce an error because of course a dictionary object is not a string.

So I would like to

-accumulate the contents of what I would like to NSLog out in a series of strings summing it all up

-this includes the printing out the contents of dictionary objects (or maybe array objects too) converting it to a string, and adding it to outputString.

Anyone have any advice on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something about value: %@", dictionaryItem]

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, I just used it like this...

     myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",a,b,c]; 

which worked nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a serialized version of the NSDictionary by...

```
NSLog(@"%@", dictionaryItem);
```

assuming your instance of NSDictionary is named `dictionaryItem`.

It will output the dictionary object similar to...

```
{
    key1 = test;
    key2 = 1;
    key3 =     (
        blah
    );
}
```